# The middleware of the next js is calling repeatedly while redirecting

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, next.js13

the middleware of the next js is calling repeatedly while redirecting a user based on condition, when I am checking the user's login status by checking the session existence and trying to redirect users based on their role then I am getting a "Too Many Redirects error" on the browser.

This error happens only when I am trying to redirect a logged-in user to the /admin page but surprisingly when I am trying to redirect a not logged-in user to the /login page it works fine but the same line of code is not working for the /admin page

**This  line is not working**

```
return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/admin`);
```

**This  line is working**

```
return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/login`);
```

**Here is my whole code of the middleware.js page**

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

export async function middleware(request) {
  const session = await getToken({
    req: request,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  });

  const userRole = session?.user?.role.toLowerCase();
  const { nextUrl } = request;

  if (session !== null) {
    if (userRole === "admin" && nextUrl.pathname === "/admin") {
      return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/admin`); // this one is not working
  } else {
    if (
      nextUrl.pathname === "/admin"
    ) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/login`); // this one is working
    }
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/donor/:path*", "/agent/:path*"],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Too Many Redirectes` error usually occurs when there is a redirection loop. In your `middleware.js` code, if a user has the "admin" role and they try to access the `/admin` page, you are redirecting them back to the `/admin` page, which causes an infinite loop.

```
if (session !== null) {
  if (userRole === "admin" && nextUrl.pathname === "/admin") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/admin`); // this creates a loop
  }
}
```

I adjusted your middleware to allow admin users to access `subpages` under `/admin` without being redirected:

```
export async function middleware(request) {
  const session = await getToken({
    req: request,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  });

  // Check if the user has a session and extract user role if present
  const userRole = session?.user?.role.toLowerCase();
  const { nextUrl } = request;

  // If the user has a session
  if (session !== null) {
    // If the user is an admin
    if (userRole === "admin") {
      // If the user is trying to access the /admin page or any subpage under /admin, let the request proceed
      if (nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/admin")) {
        return NextResponse.next(); // This allows the request to proceed without redirection
      }
    } else {
      // Logic for other roles (if any), or you can redirect non-admins away from /admin pages
      if (nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/admin")) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/login`);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // If there's no session and the user is trying to access /admin, redirect them to the login page
    if (nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/admin")) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/login`);
    }
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/donor/:path*", "/agent/:path*"],
};
```

Comment: Thanks Batman, the redirection problem is solved, but one problem is still there that is if admin trying to visit /admin/somepage then its redirecting to /admin page which is a problem

Comment: @ProgrammerInjamam I adjusted my answer. Thanks!